# Turn code into reusable Class - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm using the following code to animate a TextView's height growing from 0 to 100 (or whatever is specified as the "m" value on the animateHeight method.  My question is, how can I turn this into a class so that I can call it for all 12 of my textviews and have them all animate at the same time?

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void animateHeight(int m) {        
    int maxInDp = m;
    int maxInPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, maxInDp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "barHeight", maxInPx);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(1500);
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
    objectAnimator.start(); 
}

public int barHeight = 0;

public int getBarHeight() { return barHeight; }

public void setBarHeight(int height) {
    barHeight = height;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lblSavingsSummaryChartMonth1Savings.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = barHeight;
    lblSavingsSummaryChartMonth1Savings.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried creating my own custom TextView using the code below, but I get an error static that "static" is not permitted.  If I remove it, the error goes away, but then when I run the app I get a "NoSuchMethodException "

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static class AnimatedTextView extends TextView {

public AnimatedTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);     
}   

public void animateHeight(int m) {        
    int maxInDp = 100;
    int maxInPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, maxInDp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "barHeight", maxInPx);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(1500);
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
    objectAnimator.start(); 
}

public int barHeight = 0;

public int getBarHeight() { return barHeight; }

public void setBarHeight(int height) {
    barHeight = height;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = barHeight;
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Figured it out.  In order to make it work I changed the constructor to

```
public AnimatedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
}
```

Comment: you told about "12 of your textviews" ,want to know these are inside list or in a single activity screen ?  if in single screen like any registration form ,then you should write individual code stuff 12 times for each textview .:-@Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class who extends `TextView` and put your code in it. Then, in your XML, use :

```
<com.yourpackage.YourClassExtendsTextView
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:width="match_parent"/>
```

instead of

```
<TextView
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:width="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include the custom TextView class I've created.  Are you able to give me any pointers as to why I'm getting the "NoSuchMethodException: <init>" error now?

Comment: Nevermind, I needed the constructor that provided the AttributeSet.  After updated it works perfectly now.